# Parar eventos onblur onclick mientras carga

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Hay alguna forma de parar los eventos onblur hasta que se cargue la pagina completa?

Los eventos están dentro de un formulario normal html y tienen esta pinta

```
<input disabled type="text" name="art_siglas" id="art_siglas" onblur="Guardar()" placeholder="Siglas para etiquetas" title="Siglas para la etiqueta" />
```

Y se auto completan con jQuery usando esto sin document ready:

```
$('#art_siglas').val('<?=$DMo["siglas"]; ?>');
```

Comment: Normalmente esos eventos no se crean sino hasta que carga la página completa.

Comment: Pues tengo puesto un autocompletador de inputs y se ejecuta el onblur XD @Lixus

Comment: Tendrías que agregar tu código para ver si ese autocomplete está fuera de un `$(document).ready` y en caso de... agregarlo ahí para que hasta que no esté lista la página no se cree el evento.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta con lo que estoy usando a ver si ayuda. @Lixus

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer que tu JavaScript corra después que la página se carge quita el onblur que tienes en el `<input>` así:

```
<input disabled type="text" name="art_siglas" id="art_siglas" placeholder="Siglas para etiquetas" title="Siglas para la etiqueta" />
```

Crea el onblur usando JQuery después que la página se carge:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#art_siglas').blur(function(){
      // el código que tienes en GetBlur() va aquí
   });
   $('#art_siglas').val('<?=$DMo["siglas"]; ?>');
});
```

También se puede escribir así, ambas formas son lo mismo:

```
$(function(){
   $('#art_siglas').blur(function(){
      // el código que tienes en GetBlur() va aquí
   });

   $('#art_siglas').val('<?=$DMo["siglas"]; ?>');
});
```

Cuando no necesites el `blur` puedes llamar

```
$('#art_siglas').off( "blur" );
```

Comment: Pero así lo malo es que como la pagina se genera en vivo cuando meto los datos al formulario ya tengo cargada la pagina, con lo que ya esta activo el blur. Necesitaría mas bien alguna forma de poder parar el evento en vivo

Comment: Le añadí a la respuesta el código que necesitas para quitar el `blur`.